# docker-compose and 127.0.0.1 internal access to service

Tags: docker, network-programming, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` configuration (simplified for presentation reasons):

```
version: '3'
services:
   web:
     image: tomcat:8.0.48-jre8

    db:
      image: postgres:9.6.6
      expose:
        - "5432"
```

and I can access `db` service from `web` service by using `postgres:5432` url. I wonder is there is a way to map/remap the internal Docker network to allow accessing mentioned `web` service from `web` service just by using `127.0.0.1:5432`?

`web` is not using/binding to `5432` port, that's why I thought it may be possible to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Each container runs in it's own network namespace by default, so localhost in one container is a different namespace from the others. There's no forwarding of ports between containers, only from the host to the container when you do a publish. Between containers, all you need is a common network, and all ports are available, so you don't even need the expose command, but you do need to specify the ip or dns name of the target container.

It wouldn't be a best practice, but you can use the network namespace of another container. I only do this when debugging a running container's network with something like the netshoot tool, e.g.:

```
docker run -it --rm --net container:$container_id nicolaka/netshoot netstat -lnt
```

That command would create a second container that uses the same network namespace as an existing container, and show you the listening network ports on that network.